# How to use HERE in Stata "georoute"?

Tags: stata

I use Stata in my finance research on startup companies. We want to estimate the distance between a company's address and the address of its board members. I have the related zip-codes' coordinates, but struggle to get the integration with HERE to work. The main challenge seems to be to find the "herecode" to include in the command. Grateful for any suggestions. See the extract from Stat's help text on georoute here:

georoute calculates the georouting distance between two addresses or two geographical points identified by their coordinates.  It uses the HERE application programming interface (API) (https://developer.here.com) to retrieve distances in two steps:  In the first step, addresses are geocoded, and their geographical coordinates (latitude and longitude) are obtained.  In the second step, the georouting distance between the two points is obtained.  The user can also provide directly geographical coordinates, which will bypass the first step.

Options for georoute

hereid(string) and herecode(string) indicate the App ID and App Code of the user.  Before using this command, the user must therefore get an HERE account at
https://developer.here.com.  hereid() and herecode() are required.

Comment: Are you using an outdated version of `georoute`? In the most recent version I only see `herekey` as a compulsory field; this is the API key received when signing up for a [HERE account](https://developer.here.com/sign-up?create=Freemium-Basic&keepState=true&step=account). On the freemium account you get 250k api calls per month but can pay for more.

Comment: Thank you!  I use Stata 16 and simply downloaded georoute with the instructions quoted. Would you know how to find a more recent version?  Best, Aksel

Comment: Yes, you have a couple of options there. I will add a proper answer below!

Comment: Please accept the answer from @JR96 if it answers the question to your satisfaction.

Answer (score 1):

**Updating the Package**

There are a couple of options for updating the package. You could `ssc install {pckgname}` where it will check for the most recent version and replace if outdated. To be safe I would usually do something like this:

```
ado uninstall georoute
ssc install georoute

* Install companion packages (needed to run georoute)
ssc install insheetjson
ssc install libjson
```

Then hopefully browsing `help georoute` will confirm that `hereid` is the only HERE credential needed.